# Remove measured distribution from another distribution

Tags: statistics, signal-processing

Take a particle beam as an ensemble of many particles. Assume two independent random variables $X_\beta$ and $\delta$ that add up to the horizontal position $X$ of a particle:

$$
X = X_\beta + D_x \delta
$$

($D_x$ is a simple number, the "dispersion" function in beam dynamics.)

I have a horizontal measurement of the beam profile, $f_X$, and another measurement of the longitudinal momentum profile, $f_\delta$. I have normalised both to unity area and take them to be measurements of the probability density functions of $X$ and $\delta$:

[image: measured beam profiles in horizontal ($f_X$) and longitudinal ($f_\delta$) plane]

Now, I would like to determine the distribution / profile of $X_\beta$.

How do I have to proceed?

A first thought was to deconvolve $f_X$ with $f_{D_x\delta}$, after I interpolated both data sets to the same set of positions. Unfortunately, I failed with `scipy.signal.deconvolve`... I end up with an error quantity equal to the spectrum, i.e. I get nowhere.

If I convolve the two, I get an extension of $f_X$ by $f_{D_x\delta}$, as I'd expect:

[image: convolution of the horizontal and longitudinal profile measurements]

(via `numpy.convolve(f_x, f_Dxdelta, 'same')` where both arrays have the same length and are w.r.t. the same positions)

I'd like to do the opposite now and 'remove' instead of 'add' the dispersive part. Or am I gone in the completely wrong direction?

One more possibly important information: I expect $X_\beta$ to have a normal distribution as opposed to $\delta$. I would like to extract the corresponding standard deviation of $X_\beta$ from $f_X$.

Thanks for your help,
Adrian

Comment: Good question. You might want to ask it on [*Cross Validated*](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Sathyam, I've added the axis labels. What do you mean by the parameters?

Comment: Thanks, @MikeDunlavey, I've added my question there as well: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/187325/

Comment: @TheXMA Noice, time of exposure(may not be relevant).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (among other things) because it was cross-posted.

Comment: @Sathyam, noise has been filtered out by a Savitzky-Golay filter on the blue curve, the measured "PDF" of $X$. I think, time of exposure / gains of the wire scanners don't really play a role as I cannot immediately repeat the measurements...

Comment: I have actually found a possible approach to solve for the $\sigma_{x_\beta}$. I'll post it on Cross Validated as the question here has been put on hold by @Qmechanic. If you unhold it, I could answer -- I think it might be relevant to other experimentalists as well...

Comment: @Qmechanic I second TheXMA's opinion. It is relevant to experimentalists like me. Requesting to unhold.

Comment: Let's first see the answer at Cross Validated. A 3k+ user can then vote to reopen the Phys.SE post if appropriate.